# ¿Como puedo pasar un array de un script a otro?

Tags: php, laravel

verán, tengo un sistema de venta en un hosting, el cual como comprobante de venta imprime el ticket, por obvias razones no lo puedo imprimir desde el hosting, así que uso XAMPP como intermediario, le mando los datos y este se encarga de imprimir el ticket, todo va bien hasta que quiero mandar el array, estoy manejando el método POST, alguien tiene una idea de como pudiera hacerlo?, o alguna idea mas sencilla para hacerlo, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Puedes codificar tu array con json y enviarlo con ajax, o tal vez puedas resolverlo solo con php, depende, hace falta que agregues más información de lo que necesitas

Comment: No entiendo por qué no se puede imprimir desde un hosting, o no me queda claro por lo menos.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas mandar un array lo puedes hacer así:

```
array = [
           variable1 =>  'valor',
           variable2 =>  'valor',
           etc.. 
      ]
```

también podrías mandarlo en formato json:

```
json = { variable1 : 'valor', variable2 : 'valor'}
```

Comment: Lo podría hacer con  $ajax